# Group by with condition query using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query, I am just trying group by with condition.

```
select 
    CardType, TypeTitle, EducationType, typetitle, customertype  
from 
    #temprec 
group by 
    (case when CardType = 2 then CardType else CustomerType),
    CardType, TypeTitle, EducationType, typetitle, customertype
```

But I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

What would be the cause for this?

Comment: You are stil using CardType and customertype  in group by

Comment: Your `CASE` expression needs to finish with an `END` i.e. `(case when  CardType =2  then CardType else CustomerType END)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just missed `end` after else

```
select 
        CardType, TypeTitle, EducationType, typetitle, customertype  
    from 
        #temprec 
    group by 
        (case when CardType = 2 then CardType else CustomerType end),
        CardType, TypeTitle, EducationType, typetitle, customertype
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not require the `CASE` at all because both `CardType` and `CustomerType` are already in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select CardType, TypeTitle, EducationType, typetitle, customertype  
from #temprec t
group by CardType, TypeTitle, EducationType, typetitle, customertype ;
```

I question the need for the `GROUP BY`, because you have no aggregation functions. You can even add the expression to the `SELECT`:

```
select distinct (case when CardType = 2 then CardType else CustomerType end),
       CardType, TypeTitle, EducationType, typetitle, customertype  
from #temprec t;
```

Note that this could get a type conversion error if `CardType` and `CustomerType` have different types.